# How do i delete and update a row data using http calls in angular 2?

Tags: angular, http

I trying to do employee add delete and update data in angular. 
I am able to add data to the array. But I am unable to update and delete my data.

Can someone tell me how to do an HTTP call for delete and update?

This is my code in component and service.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    import { Observable} from 'rxjs';
    import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

    import { Employee } from './employee';
    import { EmployeeService} from './employee.service';

    @Component({
        selector: 'employee-form',
        templateUrl: './employee-form.component.html',
        styleUrls: ['./employee-form.component.css']
    })

    export class EmployeeFormComponent{
        employees : Employee[];
        errorMessage : String;
        id : number;
        firstName : String;
        lastName  : String;
        EmployeeType : String;
        employee = new Employee();
        clicked = false;
        constructor(private employeeservice : EmployeeService){}
        ngOnInit(): void{
            this.fetchEmployees();
        }
            fetchEmployees(): void{
                this.employeeservice.getDetailsFromJson()
                .subscribe( employees => this.employees = employees,
                                        error => this.errorMessage = <any>error)
            }

            addEmployee(): void{
                this.employeeservice.addEmployees(this.employee)
                .subscribe(employee => {
                    this.fetchEmployees();
                        this.reset();
                        this.firstName = employee.firstname;
                        this.lastName = employee.lastname;
                        this.EmployeeType = employee.employeetype;
                        this.clicked = false;
                }, 
                error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
            }
            deleteEmp(): void {
                    this.employeeservice.delete(this.employee.id).then(() => 
            }

            private reset(){
                this.employee.firstname = null; 
                this.employee.lastname = null;
                this.employee.employeetype = null;
            }
    }
```

Service :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response,Headers,RequestOptions} from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import {Employee} from './employee'

@Injectable()
    export class EmployeeService {
            empurl = 'api/employees';
            constructor (private http:Http){}
            getDetailsFromJson():Observable<Employee[]>{
                return this.http.get(this.empurl)
                        .map(this.extractData)
                        .catch(this.HandleErrorObservable);                        
            }
            addEmployees(employee: Employee): Observable<Employee>{
                let headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
                let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});
                return this.http.post(this.empurl,employee,options)
                        .map(this.extractData)
                        .catch(this.HandleErrorObservable)
            }
            delete(id: number): Promise<void> {
                let headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
                let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});
    const url = `${this.empurl}/${id}`;
    return this.http.delete(url, options)
      .toPromise()
      .then(() => null)
      .catch(this.HandleErrorObservable);
  }

            private extractData(res: Response){
                let body= res.json();
                return body.data || {}
            }
            private HandleErrorObservable(error : Response | any){
                console.log(error.message || error);
                return Observable.throw( error.message || error);
            }
    }
```

Template:

```
<h3>Employee Details</h3>
<div class="container"> 
  <div>
    <table class="table table-stripped table-bordered">
      <tr><th>Id</th><th>Firstname</th><th>Lastname</th><th>EmployeeType</th><th>Actions</th></tr>
      <tr *ngFor="let employee of employees"[class.selected]="employee === selectedEmployee">
        <td>{{employee.id}}</td>
        <td>{{employee.firstname}}</td>
        <td>{{employee.lastname}}</td>
        <td>{{employee.employeetype}}</td>
        <td><button class="btn btn-default" (click)="deleteEmp(); $event.stopPropagation()">Delete</button>
            <button class="btn btn-default" (click)="updateEmp(); $event.stopPropagation()"> Update</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div [hidden]="submitted">
<div class="container" >
    <h1>Employee Form</h1>
    <form class="form-horizontal" (ngSubmit) = "addEmployee()" #employeeform="ngForm">
      <div class="form-group ">
        <label for="firstname" class="control-label col-md-3">FirstName:</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
        <input type="text" class="form-control col-md-6" id="firstname" required [(ngModel)]="employee.firstname" name="firstname" >


      </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="lastname" class="control-label col-md-3">LastName:</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastname" required [(ngModel)]="employee.lastname" name="lastname">

        </div>
      </div>

      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success "  [disabled]="!employeeform.form.valid" value="submit">


    </form>
    </div>
    </div>
```

If someone explain how its done its much appreciated.

Comment: Well... this all depends on what your backend is expecting. Unless we know that, we can't advise how to perform the requests :)

Comment: Well i am using a InMemoryWebApiModule for Db

Comment: Have you checked the  official docs: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt6.html? Seems you are missing filtering out the selected "hero" from your `deleteEmp` function. You just have `.then(() => }`

Comment: I am using a table for my employees Can i use selected for a table too?
I updated my template Please check it..

Comment: Not sure what you mean? Now I also see that you are not passing the employee which you want to delete in the template, how does angular know which employee to delete? :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't have enough reputation to comment....

One way is to delete the row by passing the unique attribute that your backend is expecting.. and then reload the view by getting the data from backend to keep in sync.
Again this depends on your architecture.

If you don't want to make a back end call, just slice the data u deleted from the array after the delete call is success.